# How to have have a non-interrupted online stream with ffplay?

Tags: ffmpeg, mplayer

I use the command

```
ffplay -i $(youtube-dl -g -f 94 \
"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nxid1JTdfrk")
```

to stream Euronews. There are however some interruptions due to insufficient cache.

**Which option, equivalent to `-cache` for `mplayer` allows me to set the cache in other to avoid interruptions?**

PS: I am looking for a solution for `ffplay` (I don't want to pipe the `ffmpeg` stream to `mplayer`).